# Passing a list through <a href = "{% url 'list_item' %}"> in django

Tags: python, django

I have to add links to list items listed in the main body of the page that redirect the user to the page that the list items represent. The list items are fetched from a function in views.py which fetches the list items from another file named util.py. However, I don't understand how to add those hyperlinks while iterating through the list items i.e the part I wrote as `<a href = "{% url '....' %}">`.
This is the code for index.html, the page where the list items along with the hyperlinks are to be shown:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><a href = "{% url '....' %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the function that gets the list from util.py and stores it in a list named `entries`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from . import util


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })
```

This is the orginal function from util.py that returns the list to the `index` function in views.py.

```
def list_entries():
    """
    Returns a list of all names of encyclopedia entries.
    """
    _, filenames = default_storage.listdir("entries")
    return list(sorted(re.sub(r"\.md$", "", filename)
                for filename in filenames if filename.endswith(".md")))
```

This is the urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
app_name = "wiki"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:TITLE>", views.entry_page, name="entry_page")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. No?

```
<li><a href ="/{{entry}}/">{{ entry }}</a></li>
```

Comment: Gives this error when I do that: `TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '/{{entry}}/' from '/{{entry}}/'`

Answer (score 0):

I almost gave up on the project as this error wouldn't allow me to continue with the project and I didn't want to spend more time finding a solution for this problem. However, today I decided to give it a final push and found a solution!
So the main error was in urls.py. As the path was supposed to be dynamic due to the changing items in the list, its name field was supposed to be a variable too. However, I had given it a static name. This is the line I am talking about: `path("<str:TITLE>", views.entry_page, name="entry_page")`
The name is set to a `entry_page` which is simply a string. It should have been named as `TITLE` instead which is a variable I have used throughout my code for the entries. Therefore, the modifications would be `path("<str:TITLE>", views.entry_page, name="TITLE")` in urls.py and `<li><a href = "{% url 'wiki:TITLE' TITLE=entry %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>` in index.html.

Comment: This bit of Django Documentation helped in understanding the solution: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 0):

**`<a href= "wiki/{{ entry }}"><li>{{ entry }}</li></a>`**

after tries and error this is what works. Got this from inspecting the  HTML   that is added by default in the CSS page.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it is not 'dynamic'. a better solution is to use the `url` builtin of Django. See documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url